# « Faire couler les érables de bonne heure »

Tags: sens, expressions-idiomatiques, québec

Que signifie l'expression idiomatique « faire couler les érables de bonne heure » ? La voici dans un extrait d'un article du Devoir :

> Je vous écoute déchirer votre chemise pour faire des tapis de catalogne depuis une semaine. La laïcité, la charte, les accommodements et le foutu voile. Cette question qui brasse l’identitaire fait couler les érables de bonne heure cette année. On dirait que vous avez tous lu Soumission de Michel Houellebecq.
>   — [« Le vent dans « les » voiles »](http://www.ledevoir.com/societe/actualites-en-societe/492511/le-vent-dans-les-voiles), Josée Blanchette

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dans le domaine de l'[acériculture](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8358384)<sup>1</sup> (ou traditionnellement chez les peuples des Premières Nations du Canada), on [entaille](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/entaille) l'[érable à sucre](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8869855), facilement [reconnaissable](http://ville.montreal.qc.ca/siteofficieldumontroyal/vegetal-indigene/erable-a-sucre), dont la largeur du tronc est supérieure à 20 cm (45 ans), au début du printemps. Mais il ne s'agit pas d'une date fixe, mais plutôt d'un moment, qui s'est produit il y a à peu près une [dizaine de jours](http://affaires.lapresse.ca/economie/agroalimentaire/201702/25/01-5073175-le-redoux-prete-main-forte-aux-acericulteurs-quebecois.php), « lorsque les nuits de gel sont suivies par des jours de dégel (température diurne positive, journée idéalement ensoleillée, et température nocturne négative) » (Wikipédia) permettant à l'eau d'érable de remonter des racines vers le haut de l'arbre ; on en obtient les différents produits de l'érable, dont le [sirop](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sirop_d'%C3%A9rable), par l'ébullition contrôlée. *De bonne heure* signifie [tôt, en avance sur le temps ou l'époque](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/heure/39843/locution?q=de%20bonne%20heure#173005), et donc en contexte *tôt en saison*. Enfin on a [*faire couler beaucoup d'encre*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/couler), pour *faire écrire beaucoup à son sujet* (TLFi).

---

Ce qui donne à mon avis une analogie saisonnière et pittoresque, ancrée dans la réalité de la tradition acéricole québécoise avec l'eau qui coule de l'entaille pratiquée dans le tronc de l'érable à sucre, dont le modèle ressemble à celui de l'expression qui précède (*faire couler beaucoup d'encre*), pour quelque chose comme *faire écrire beaucoup à son sujet tôt dans l'année*, avec l'idée de réchauffement, et du dégel printanier, etc.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> « Culture et exploitation d’une érablière en vue de la récolte, du traitement et de la transformation de la sève d’érable » (GDT) ; « Au Canada, exploitation industrielle d'une érablière pour produire du sirop d'érable » ([Larousse](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/ac%C3%A9riculture/611?q=ac%C3%A9riculture#380816)). Pour l'industrie [acér](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/%C3%A9rable)icole québécoise, voir [statistiques](http://www.stat.gouv.qc.ca/statistiques/agriculture/acericulture-erable/index.html), monographies ([1](https://www.mapaq.gouv.qc.ca/fr/Publications/RapportErableFINAL.pdf), [2](https://www.mapaq.gouv.qc.ca/fr/Publications/Monographie_acericole.pdf), [fpaq](http://fpaq.ca/)).</sub>

Comment: alors l'acériculture c'est l'art de lacérer (les érables) ?

Comment: Non, comme l'édicte l'article 27 de la [_Loi sur la protection du territoire et des activités agricoles_](http://www.canlii.org/fr/qc/legis/lois/rlrq-c-p-41.1/derniere/rlrq-c-p-41.1.html) du Québec, on ne peut « utiliser une érablière située dans une région agricole désignée à une autre fin [que l'agriculture], ni y faire la coupe des érables [...] » ; l'utilisation dont vous parlez serait interdite. L'érable est entaillé et produit l'eau et la sève sa vie durant (300 ans). Enfin _acer_ est le mot latin pour [_érable_](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/%C3%A9rable). D'autres questions ? Merci.

Answer (score 1):

Je crois que je sais d'où vient l'expression. Josée Blanchette est Québecoise, et au Québec, on fait du sirop d'érable, en faisant "saigner" les érables et en récupérant leur sève, et je crois que c'est au début du printemps. Par contre, je ne sais pas très bien ce que cela voudrait dire: peut-être que les esprits s'échauffent sur *cette question*, si l'on suppose que le printemps est la saison où les esprits s'échauffent.